# Get JavaScript Parameteres using selenium+BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I would like to know what is the most efficient way to get the javascript config params using Selenium + BS4.
I would like to get the input parameter in the following script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    
        require.config.params['matchheader'] = {
            input: [162,13,'Crystal Palace','Arsenal','05/08/2022 20:00:00','05/08/2022 00:00:00',6,'FT','0 : 1','0 : 2',,,'0 : 2','England','England']
    ,
            matchId: 1640674
        };


</script>
```

[Source Page](https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1640674/Show/Portugal-Liga-Portugal-2022-2023-Rio-Ave-Vizela)

Any idea on how to do it?

Regards

Comment: what info are you looking for exactly, in that page?

Comment: The site is protected with Incapsula `firewall protection`, so if you are using selenium so i think you can pickup it using regex `input: \[.*?\]`

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it's global, so just:

```
object = driver.execute_script("return require.config.params['matchheader']")
```